# How to Reverse the delimited parts of a string

Tags: r, hierarchy, concatenation

I'm trying to reverse the parts of a hierarchical name found in a dataframe so that I can work with the string for the reverse path. Here is what I did:

```
flip <- function(x) {                      # My attempted function
  str <- str_split(x,":",simplify=TRUE)
  paste(str[length(str):1], collapse = ":")
}

Data <- data.frame(                        # The data
  X = c("one:two:three:four","five:six:seven:eight")
)

mutate(Data,                               # My attempt & result
   Xflip = flip(X)
)
#>                     X                Xflip
#>1   one:two:three:four eight:four:seven:three:six:two:five:one
#>2 five:six:seven:eight eight:four:seven:three:six:two:five:one


# What I am looking for
#>                     X                Xflip
#>1   one:two:three:four   four:three:two:one
#>2 five:six:seven:eight eight:seven:six:five
```

Thank you!

Comment: My apologies -- there are some typos in my example above. I will edit my example. Thanks for response so far.

Comment: It's not clear to me that this is an exact duplicate as I need to reverse the parts of a delimited string rather than each character in the string. I've edited the title to reflect this difference. I note that in the "How to reverse a string in R" article a strsplit is performed but employs NULL as delimiter - not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd split, flip, then concatenate. But there might be an easier way using mutate :)

```
flipper <- function(x){

    splitVector <- unlist(strsplit(x, ":")) #Split it by ":"
    flipVector <- rev(splitVector ) #Reverse it
    flipString <- paste0(flipVector, collapse = ":") #Paste it back together!
    return(flipString)

}
```

That should do the job for you!

```
Data$Xflip <- sapply(as.character(Data$X), flipper)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using `stringr::str_split_fixed`:

```
df$Xflip <- apply(stringr::str_split_fixed(df$X, ":", 4), 1, function(x) 
    paste0(rev(x), collapse = ":"))
#                     X                Xflip
#1   one:two:three:four   four:three:two:one
#2 five:six:seven:eight eight:seven:six:five
```

Or using `stringr::str_split`:

```
df$Xflip <- sapply(stringr::str_split(df$X, ":"), function(x) 
    paste0(rev(x), collapse = ":"));
```

You can do the same using `transform`:

```
transform(df, Xflip = sapply(stringr::str_split(X, ":"), function(x) 
    paste0(rev(x), collapse = ":")))
```

The `stringr::str_split` method will also work if `X` contains a varying number of `":"` separated entries.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I've obviously got more to learn about R programming. You've inspired me to "dig in" a bit more.

Comment: No worries @A.Maffei; glad I could help. Please consider upvoting if the answer was useful.